# Custom Word Jumble Game

Tags: c++

I'm making another version of a word jumble game I did for a project. I used the same setup for the game itself from my original code, but this one does something different with the files. Like before, it puts words into a `string array` from a file and then uses words from the array to shuffle and prints out the jumbled word for the user to unscramble.

The difference is with this program, it allows the user to choose what group of words they want to use for the scramble. The program compiles fine, but after they've chosen what type of file to use (and created the file if they need to), the program stops running. I've posted the code below, is there something in the code causing it to stop running? If so, I'd love some tips on fixing it along with an explanation for why it caused a problem.

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void createFile(ofstream& file, string fileName, int wordCount) {
    string word;
    file.open(fileName + ".txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
        cout << "Enter a word: \n";
        cin >> word;
        file << word;
        file << endl;
    }
    file.close();
} 

void useFile(ifstream& file, string fileName) {
    file.open(fileName + ".txt");
}

void main() {
    srand(time(0));
    int levelChoice, wordCount, i = 0;
    string fileName, word, jumble, answer;
    string words[10000];
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;
    bool repeat = true, result, allowed = false;
    char choice;

    cout << "Let's play a word jumble game!\n";
    cin.get();
    do {
        cout << "First, choose what you want to use to play.\n";
        cout << "(1) Pre-made word list file\n(2) Custom file\n";
        cin >> levelChoice;
        do {
            if (levelChoice == 1) {
                cout << "Okay, please choose what you'd like to play!\n";
                cout << "(1) Easy\n(2) Medium\n(3) Hard\n(4) Theme\n";
                cin >> levelChoice;
                if (levelChoice == 4) {
                    cout << "Please select a theme: \n";
                    cout << "(1) Colors\n(2) Emotions\n(3) Flowers\n(4) Nature\n(5) Seasons\n(6) Animals\n";
                    cin >> levelChoice;
                    switch (levelChoice) {
                    case 1:
                        infile.open("Theme (Colors).txt");
                        while (infile.peek() != EOF) {
                            infile >> words[i];
                            i++;
                        }
                        infile.close();
                        allowed = true;
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        infile.open("Theme (Emotions).txt");
                        while (infile.peek() != EOF) {
                            infile >> words[i];
                            i++;
                        }
                        infile.close();
                        allowed = true;
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        infile.open("Theme (Flowers).txt");
                        while (infile.peek() != EOF) {
                            infile >> words[i];
                            i++;
                        }
                        infile.close();
                        allowed = true;
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        infile.open("Theme (Nature).txt");
                        while (infile.peek() != EOF) {
                            infile >> words[i];
                            i++;
                        }
                        infile.close();
                        allowed = true;
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        infile.open("Theme (Seasons).txt");
                        while (infile.peek() != EOF) {
                            infile >> words[i];
                            i++;
                        }
                        infile.close();
                        allowed = true;
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        infile.open("Theme (Animals).txt");
                        while (infile.peek() != EOF) {
                            infile >> words[i];
                            i++;
                        }
                        infile.close();
                        allowed = true;
                        break;

                    default:
                        cout << "That was not an option, please try again.\n";
                        break;
                    }
                } 
                else if (levelChoice < 1 || levelChoice > 4) {
                    cout << "Sorry, that was not a valid option, please try again.\n";
                } else {
                    switch (levelChoice) {
                    case 1:
                        infile.open("Easy.txt");
                        while (infile.peek() != EOF) {
                            infile >> words[i];
                            i++;
                        }
                        infile.close();
                        allowed = true;
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        infile.open("Medium.txt");
                        while (infile.peek() != EOF) {
                            infile >> words[i];
                            i++;
                        }
                        infile.close();
                        allowed = true;
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        infile.open("Hard.txt");
                        while (infile.peek() != EOF) {
                            infile >> words[i];
                            i++;
                        }
                        infile.close();
                        allowed = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else if (levelChoice == 2) {
                cout << "Okay, please enter the file name:\n";
                cin >> fileName;
                cout << "Now tell me how many words you'd like to enter into the file so I can create it: ";
                cin >> wordCount;
                cout << "Time to create your file!\n";
                createFile(outfile, fileName, wordCount);
                useFile(infile, fileName);
                while (infile.peek() != EOF) {
                    infile >> words[i];
                    i++;
                }
                infile.close();
                cout << "File created, you're ready to play!";
                cin.get();
                cin.get();
                allowed = true;
            } else {
                cout << "That was not a valid option, please try again!\n";
            }
        } while (allowed == false);

        int guess = 0;
        int size = sizeof(words);
        int random = rand() % size;
        jumble = words[random];
        random_shuffle(jumble.begin(), jumble.end());
        cout << "Time to start guessing!\nType \"quit\" if you want to give up and find out the word!\nCareful though, you only get 10 guesses before you lose!\n";
        cin.get();
        cin.get();
        cout << jumble << endl;
        do {
            cin >> answer;
            if (answer == "quit" || answer == "Quit") {
                cout << "Giving up? Okay! Ready to find out what the word was?";
                cin.get();
                cin.get();
                cout << "The word was " << words[random] << endl;
                cout << "Better luck next time!\n";
                break;
            } else {
                result = strcmp(answer.c_str(), words[random].c_str());
                if (result == true) {
                    cout << "Nope! Try again!" << endl;
                    guess++;
                } else {
                    cout << "You got it!" << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (guess < 10);

        if (guess == 10) {
            cout << "Game over! You lose! Ready to find out what the jumbled word was?";
            cin.get();
            cin.get();
            cout << "The word was " << words[random] << endl << "Better luck next time!";
        }

        cout << "Wanna play again? (Y or N)\n";
        cin >> choice;
        do {
            switch (choice) {
            case 'y':
            case 'Y':
                cout << "Okay, restarting!\n";
                cin.get();
                cin.get();
                allowed = false;
                break;

            case 'n':
            case 'N':
                cout << "Okay, have a great day!\n";
                repeat = false;
                allowed = false;
                break;

            default:
                cout << "Sorry, that was not a valid option, please try again!\n";
                break;
            }
        } while (allowed == true);
    } while (repeat == true);
}
```

Comment: I suggest breaking up `main` into logical functions instead of having one gigantic `main()` function with a colossal `do-while` loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "the program stops running"?  Does the program close?  Are there any exceptions that are being thrown?

Comment: Avoid having to `while (infile.peek() != EOF)` with something more like `while (infile >> words[i])( i++; }` This reads and tests that you got something before incrementing `i`. Your version tests then reads leaving the validity of the read questionable and increments `i` regardless.

Comment: Also, all 6 of your cases in the `switch` statement do the same thing.  The only difference is the name of the file.   Imagine if there were 100 files, would you write 100 `case` statements that do the same thing? You could simply store the names in a string array and use the level number as an index into the string array, thus eliminating the code duplication.

Comment: Look closer at your `if...else` logic for `levelChoice`.  Is it really doing what you want it to do?

Comment: There are so many things that can go wrong with this code.  Another thing is that if you have more than 10000 words, your program exhibits undefined behavior.  Use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of a `std::string` array of 10000 elements.  Also it's `int main()`, not `void main()`.

Comment: Much appreciated everyone! I'll go through the code and edit it based on your input and see what happens!

Also, @PaulMcKenzie I use `void main()` because I initially learned that main functions don't have a return type (and I'm admittedly lazy and don't have the patience to use `return 0;` every time I write a program). It hasn't caused any noticeable problems with my code, nor has it been corrected by my teacher so I don't feel the need to change it, but the input is still greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you're calling `sizeof(words)`, which returns the number of bytes the `words` array contains, not the number of entries in the array. The result is that `size` ends up being very large (like 240,000), so the call to `rand % size` will potentially generate a value that's greater than the number of elements in the array and you'll index past the end of the array.

You can find these types of issues by running your application using a debugger. Generally, a debugger will stop your program on the line that caused the problem and show you the state of your program's variables so you can figure out what went wrong.